# Chef mount resource failing with access denied by server while mounting

Tags: chef-infra, mount

Hi I am writing a chef recipe to mount a nfs server but I keep getting

```
STDERR: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '32'
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
mount node['recipe']['var_mount'] do
  device node['recipe']['var_mount_location'].to_s
  fstype 'nfs'
  options 'vers=3,intr,soft,rw,noatime'
  action [:mount, :enable]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i can think of a few scenarios:

1. chef-client is not running as root, thus have no sufficient permissions to modify the system
2. the nfs resource (drive) is not ready when chef-client executes your recipe

i will advise you to run chef-client with debug log level, such as:

```
$ chef-client --log_level debug
```